# Cloud functions execution completed without error but it doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, firebase, canvas, google-cloud-functions

I am using Face API to detect the number of faces in images and cloud functions execution gets completed every time but nothing changes in the database. Everything is fine with other cloud functions to create and update profile but this is not working as expected. I have added lots of console.log statements in this function for anyone to point out where the error is, hereafter calling `const img = await canvas.loadImage(imgUrl);` no more console.log statements get printed in logs of cloud functions but there is no error too which is making it really hard to debug. Someone, please point out the error.

Face API documentation:
https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js#face-api.js-for-nodejs

P.S: Image URL is correct here I just changed it.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const stringHash = require('string-hash');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.verifyProfile = functions.runWith({
  memory: '1GB'
}).https.onCall(async (data) => {

  console.log('====================== Cloud function called ==================')
  console.log(data);
  require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

  const faceApi = require('face-api.js');
  console.log('Loaded successfully face api');

  const canvas = require('canvas');
  const { Canvas, Image, ImageData } = canvas;
  console.log('Loaded successfully canvas');

  faceApi.env.monkeyPatch({ Canvas, Image, ImageData });
  console.log('Loaded successfully modules');

  let imgUrl = 'IMAGE_URL';
  console.log('Loading new models');

  await faceApi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromDisk('./models');
  await faceApi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromDisk('./models');
  await faceApi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromDisk('./models');
  console.log('loaded new models');

  const img = await canvas.loadImage(imgUrl);
  console.log('Image converted to buffer');

  const detections = await faceApi
    .detectAllFaces(img)
    .withFaceLandmarks()
    .withFaceDescriptor();

  console.log('All detections called successfully');
  console.log(detections.length);

  const hashedValue = stringHash(data['uid']);
  const documentReference = admin.firestore().collection('profiles').doc(hashedValue);

  return documentReference.set({
    'verified': detections.length
  }, { merge: true })
});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you click the little arrow beside "Function execution took 9545 ms", does it give you any more information?

Comment: No, it doesn't show anything

Comment: My guess is it can't load the image for some reason. That would mean a failed promise. I believe in async/await syntax you can catch this with `let img; try { img = await canvas.loadImage(imgUrl); } catch (err) { console.error('error fetching image', err); }`. But you can probably see the error if you look in the networking tab of the browser dev tools.

Comment: It seems that the data is not present, after you print the line with the string "'====================== Cloud function called =================='", you print the "Data", but I can't see any information in the images posted. Could you print each field in the "Data" parameter? Also, could you save some dummy data in your database to test the connectivity? The data could be hardcoded in the function.